# how to install gdb 9.1 on debian from source code

Tags: makefile, gdb

I like to compile and use gdb 9.1. the source is here https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/

Plus when I type make in `config` directory make says `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.` because there is not make file. on root folder there are `Makefile.in` and `Makefile.tpl` and `Makefile.def`. what are these files. and how can I install gdb 9 from source code.

**Update**

After the comment changes I made in command by `G.M` I am getting this error I think almost at the end of compiling process

> mv GDBvn.new GDBvn.texi
> /home/fawad/Desktop/gdb/gdb/gdb-9.1.1/missing makeinfo --split-size=5000000 --split-size=5000000   -I /home/fawad/Desktop/gdb/gdb

> /gdb-9.1.1/gdb/doc/../../readline/readline/doc -I /home/fawad/Desktop

> /gdb/gdb/gdb-9.1.1/gdb/doc/../mi -I /home/fawad/Desktop/gdb/gdb/gdb-9.1.1/gdb/doc 
> -o gdb.info /home/fawad/Desktop/gdb/gdb/gdb-9.1.1/gdb/doc/gdb.texinfo
> /home/fawad/Desktop/gdb/gdb/gdb-9.1.1/missing: 81: makeinfo: not found

> WARNING: 'makeinfo' is missing on your system.
> You should only need it if you modified a '.texi' file, or
> any other file indirectly affecting the aspect of the manual.
> You might want to install the Texinfo package:
> http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/
> The spurious makeinfo call might also be the consequence of
> using a buggy 'make' (AIX, DU, IRIX), in which case you might
> want to install GNU make:
> http://www.gnu.org/software/make/

> make[4]: *** [Makefile:490: gdb.info] Error 127

> make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/fawad/Desktop/gdb/gdb/gdb-9.1/build/build/gdb/doc'

> make[3]: *** [Makefile:2010: subdir_do] Error 1

> make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fawad/Desktop/gdb/gdb/gdb-9.1/build/build/gdb'

> make[2]: *** [Makefile:1655: all] Error 2
> make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/fawad/Desktop/gdb/gdb/gdb-9.1/build/build/gdb'

> make[1]: *** [Makefile:9564: all-gdb] Error 2

> make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/fawad/Desktop/gdb/gdb/gdb-9.1/build/build'

> make: *** [Makefile:852: all] Error 2

Comment: Why do you `"...type make in config directory"`?  The usual instructions are to run `./configure` and then `make` in the top level directory.

Comment: @G.M. please look at my updated question. Does it mean I need to install `texinfo`

Comment: Why GDB 9 when GDB 10 has been released? On Linux, see also http://linuxfromscratch.org/

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch whats the difference between new and GDB 9. besides being new

Comment: It is documented on the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) website and in `ChangeLog` files inside the source code

Comment: As the error says you need `makeinfo`.  It's part of the `texinfo` package.  It's actually a long-standing (I mean, years-long) issue with GDB that it requires this program.  It shouldn't be required to build GDB but for some reason this issue never seems to get fixed, at least not permanently.

Comment: You can work around the `makeinfo` thing with `make MAKEINFO=true`; I do this occasionally on the odd host that doesn't have it installed.

Comment: @TomTromey later I found I installed two versions of python. So had to clean install linux.